# In Borderlands 2, how is my badass rank at 5516, but I just started a new game, and never played it before?

Tags: borderlands-2

So I'm just wondering how come, on a brand new save, on a brand new game, started me out with a crapload of tokens.  None of the challenges have been finished, but my current badass rank is 5516.
So I guess my question is this, does one of the dlc give you a bunch of badass tokens?  Or is my game glitched or what.  I'm hoping someone can answer this question for me.

Comment: When you say "brand new game", do you mean that you've never played it before and this was a fresh install?